# Display hebrew content in webview android

Tags: android

this is my hebrew content :

```
<string name="test">בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃</string>
```

When i display in textview it is display correct format. But when i display in webview it display wrong.

I used this but not any effects `DIR='RTL' LANG='HE' ALIGN='JUSTIFY'` in html. I want to display in webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14661) in WebView with strings that include nekudot (vowels).  Note that it appears to have been fixed in Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.x) and above.